# How can I add tow text and value for selectlistitem when I create a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I face a problem regarding the presentation of data in ASP.NET MVC 5.

I try to set a DropDownList from a query of the database, but when it runs, it show values like

```
{ resht_Name="my data", code_resht="my data", ..... }
```

I want to see only my data.

I have this controller:

```
string Txt_UserName = (Session["Index"]).ToString();
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

var school_resh = (from a in Df.Schl_reshte
                   join b in Df.reshtes on a.code_reshte equalsb.code_reshte
                   where a.id_school.Equals(Txt_UserName)
                   select new { b.reshte_name, b.code_reshte, a.maghta, a.id_reshschl
        }).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var item in school_resh)
{
    SelectListItem temp = new SelectListItem();
    temp.Text = item.ToString();
    temp.Value = item.ToString();
    list.Add(temp);
}

ViewData["schl_resh"] = list;"
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("school_reshte", ViewData["schl_resh"] as List<SelectListItem>, "--select--",new { @class = "dropdown1" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public List<SelectListItem> Travel_Agent()
        {
            var unitcode = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UnitCode"));
            string sqlquery = "  select supp_code,supp_name from li_supplier_msts  ";
            DataTable dtDRP_VALUE = _context.GetSQLQuery(sqlquery);
            List<SelectListItem> DRP_VALUE = new List<SelectListItem>();
            DRP_VALUE = (from DataRow dr in dtDRP_VALUE.Rows
                         select new SelectListItem()
                         {
                             Value = Convert.ToString(dr["supp_code"]),
                             Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToString(dr["supp_code"] + "~" + dr["supp_name"]  ))
                         }).ToList();

            return DRP_VALUE;

        }
```

controller

```
ViewBag.Travel_Agent = Travel_Agent();
```

View

```
<select  id="SuppCode" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Travel_Agent, "Value", "Text"))" class="form-control">                                                   
<option>---Select---</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Tanks for answer. But I think this code work in  ASP.NET Core or MVC Core not MVC5

Comment: ok your code is useful I use ` foreach (var item in school_resh)
            {  
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Convert.ToString("  "+item.reshte_name+" "+ item.code_reshte+" "+item.maghta), Value = Convert.ToString(item.reshte_name) });  
            }` in control and code working